# How to edit /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts and similar files and why they can (not) be edited

Tags: networking, command-line, bash, permissions, vim

I a trying to edit the following file (`ls -alstr` output):
 `0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 15 17:07 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts`

Unfortunately, if I try to edit it with `vim` or simply with something like 

`sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts` 

I get a 

`-bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts: Permission denied` 

error. Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90314/unable-to-edit-proc-sys-net-ipv4-ip-forward-in-xubuntu/90316) I was able to do 

`sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts’` 

and edit the file successfully. If I login as `root`, I can successfully execute 

`echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts` 

but I still cannot edit the file with `vim`. The attempts to `chmod` and `chown` the file also failed.

My questions are (Questions 1 & 2 have already been [answered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20578/sudo-redirect-output) but I state them for completeness):

1. Why can’t I edit the file as a normal user using `sudo` with `>`? (Because `>` is evaluated first and thus before the `sudo`)
2. Why does the `sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts’` even work? (It invokes a new terminal under `root` and executes the command that follows)
3. Why can’t I edit the file with `vim` when I am logged in as a normal user using `sudo` and/or as `root`?
4. Why can’t I edit the file permissions and/or owner even when I am root?
5. How can I make the change permanent so it stays there even after reboots?

Comment: Because your using the proc file system which is directly accessing  items set in the kernel.  See this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151440/important-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and make those adjustments (rather then directly editing)

See: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kernel-etcsysctl-conf-security-hardening/

/proc is a "virtual file system" used by the kernel and the information within the "files" is managed by the kernel and adjusted / configured by editing system configuration files (rather then files within /proc). Answers questions #3 - 5

Comment: Indeed the link provided explains 'how' to properly edit those attributes permanently (Q5). However Q3 & Q4 are still unclear to me. Since the files belong to root, shouldn't I be able to modify them using sudo and/or root user with vim and/or chmod/chown? Which attribute(s) of the file specifies that I do not have the permissions to do so, even as root?

Comment: They are not files. See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

Comment: you are most welcome.